# Java mbean application

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I use jconsole to execute methods of an mbean in a tomcat container.
When the quantity of beans is more than 100 it seems to be difficult to find a bean - particularly when the bean is deep in the hierarchy. Does another tool exist for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't look for another GUI tool if I were you. Some [Groovy+JMX](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+and+JMX) scripts would save you both time and energy. But if you still want GUI - try [eclipse-jmx](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-jmx).